# Rewrite this list-comprehension in R

Tags: python, r, list-comprehension

```
>>> [(x*y) for (x,y) in zip(range(3), (1,11,111))]
[0, 11, 222]
```

Not like this

```
> data.frame(0:2,c(1,11,111))
  X0.2 c.1..11..111.
1    0             1
2    1            11
3    2           111
> data.frame(0:2,c(1,11,111))->a
> a[1]*a[2]
  X0.2
1    0
2   11
3  222
```

but something like this

```
lapply(a, function(x)
{   ...how can I access here the parameters of x? 
    (not using x[1] or x[2])
}
```

Comment: So you want to supply a function and a list, and apply the function to elements of the list using pattern-matching?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the general pattern, perhaps

```
Map(`*`, 0:2, c(1, 11, 111))
```

or

```
unlist(Map(`*`, 0:2, c(1, 11, 111)))
```

or more explicitly

```
Map(function(x, y) x*y, 0:2, c(1, 11, 111))
```

(I like `Map` better than Steve's `mapply` because it does not simplify by default, is shorter to type, and plays well with the other functional functions documented on its man page, e.g., `Reduce`, `Filter`, and `Negate`).

An earlier answer for the particular question, since removed, was just `0:2 * c(1, 11, 111)`, which would be much more efficient.

Comment: +1 +1 +1 like this...rather than messing up with v/l/apply, `Reduce` and `Filter`?!? Appetit...

Comment: I didn't even know Map/Reduce existed. That provides a very clean,well known syntax for non-R users.

Answer (score 6):

Josh's answer is spot on, but if you want some generalization of the thing that `zip` is doing for you in the Python context, have a look at `mapply`, which "apply"s over several "things" at once, and applies a function on the `i`th element from each "thing", eg:

```
x1 <- 0:2
x2 <- c(1, 11, 111)
mapply(function(x, y) x*y, x1, x2)
## [1]   0  11 222
```

and:

```
x3 <- c(10, 20, 30)
mapply(function(x, y, z) x * y + z, x1, x2, x3)
## [1]  10  31 252
```

Update: See Martin's answer, too: he makes a good point about if you think you want `mapply`, you might really want the to use the convenience of `Map` instead.

Comment: +1 Ah, it would have helped if I knew what `zip` did.  The OP is probably looking for `mapply` and/or `Map`.  Though `do.call` would be faster in this example, since binary functions are vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear to me.  `lapply` loops over the elements of a list.  So your anonymous function would be applied to each column of `a`, but your example seems to indicate you want to apply a binary function to the two columns.

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
do.call("*",a)
# [1]   0  11 222
```