# Mousemovement in R graphic window

Tags: r

Could anyone please tell me a way to get mouse movement events? I am trying to make a zoomable time series plot

Comment: `locator()` collects mouse click information

Comment: Study the code of `quantmod::zooom`

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078575/unix-getting-mouse-coordinates-over-x-like-the-mathematica

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "zoomable time series plot" that's already written

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo')
chartSeries(SPY)
```

Now, you can zoom by either using `zoomChart`

```
zoomChart("last 6 months")
```

or, you can use the `zooom` function

```
zooom()
```

Now click somewhere on the chart, then click somewhere else on the chart to the right of where you clicked the first time, and it will zoom in using the places you clicked as the new start and end.

You can use `zoomChart` with an empty string to "unzoom" like this

```
zoomChart("")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then you can use `getGraphicsEvent` get mouse movements otherwise (or even with windows) you need to use something like the `tcltk` package.  If you only care about the mouse clicks then you can use `locator`.

What might be preferable is to use the `tkexamp` function from the `TeachingDemos` package to set up a plot that can be scrolled/zoomed using slider bars.  There are other packages that provide similar functionality, but I am less familiar with them.